# Difference in handling null values in SQL Server 2008 and 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, null, sql-server-2014

For Example, I have the following query

```
 Select * from TT where T_id not in (1,2,3)
```

In the table TT I have NULL values in the column along with other values and the above query returns all the rows which doesn't have T_id in 1,2,3 including rows with NULL values in SQL 2008 but in 2014 the query excludes 1,2,3 and NULL values and returns the remaining rows.

**Can someone explain the differences in handling the NULL values in 2008 and 2014?**

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this article](http://www.sqlmaestros.com/sql-server-not-in-clause-not-working/)? I think it is talking about the use of `NOT IN` in SQL Server 2014.

Comment: are you sure the two different database instances don't have different default values for ANSI_NULLS?

Comment: @shriop I ran select databasepropertyex('dbname', 'IsAnsiNullsEnabled') and for both version it returned `0`

Comment: how about at the table level? select uses_ansi_nulls, *
from
sys.tables
where [name] = 'TT'

Comment: Yes both the versions have the same values

Comment: This it not only about server or database default options - ANSI_NULLS can be changed by connection options. You can even have different ANS_NULLS value in your app, in ssms, in another instance of app/ssms which may cause different results of the same sql code.